# JavaScript clustered methods in sub-objects

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Here is an example :

```
var Bidule = function() {
    this.value = 8 ;

    this.calc = {
        plus : function(x) { return this.value + x ; },
        minus : function(x) { return this.value - x ; },
        square : function() { return this.value * this.value ; }
    }

    this.fn = {
        random : {
            set : function() { return this.value = random() ; },
            add : function() { return this.value += random() ; }
        }
    }
} ;

var b = new Bidule() ;
console.log(b.value) ;            // 8
console.log(b.calc.plus(4)) ;     // Error : 'this.value' is undefined.
console.log(b.fn.random.add()) ;  // Error : 'this.value' is undefined.
```

The point is to have clustered methods as it looks more elegant to me than 'b.fn_random_add()'.

It's easy to fix the 'this' reference :

```
var _plus = b.calc.plus ;
b.calc.plus = function() {
    return _plus.apply(b, arguments) ;
} ;

console.log(b.calc.plus(4)) ;     // 12
```

However neither the previous 'this.calc.plus' nor the new set one are in the Bidule's prototype.

I thought about having sub-objects with their own prototype, like :

```
this.calc = new Bidule_calc ;
```

But I wouldn't be able to set the main object 'this' reference.

Is there any other way than... :

```
b.calc.plus.call(b, 4) ;
```

... to set and call clustered methods ?

---

As I am writing this, I just found out a possible solution :

```
var context = this ;
Object.defineProperty(this.calc, 'value', {
    get : function() {
        return context.value ;
    }
}) ;
```

However, there is still a problem of uselessly duplicated functions as 'this.calc' isn't in the prototype, and 'Object.defineProperty' would be called for each instance of Bidule, so will create duplicated functions to overwride the clustered methods.

---

Edit :
I have to precise that we must use a prototype for all the methods :

```
var Bidule = function() {
    this.value = 8 ;
} ;
Bidule.prototype = {
    getValue : function() { return this.value ; }
} ;
```

Though, the Bidule's constructor and prototype have two seperated scopes.
It means we cannot share any 'var' into the constructor to be shared to the methods.

Comment: A quick "fix" is to declare `var that = this;` at the top of your main function, and then reference `that` in all submodules when you need to reference the owner `Bidule`. Second, there is no `random()` method, so you can't just do `= random() ;`, so your `fn.random.set` and `fn.random.add` won't work

Comment: Is there a reason you want your methods nested like that? It's not a typical JavaScript idiom because of the `this` issue. Why not put them directly on the `Bidule.prototype`? Then you can just do `b.plus(4)`.

Comment: @Lan : I know that `random()` doesn't exist, it was just to put a simple example. And hmm... I knew that setting `this` in a variable would work, but the prototype won't get access to the private variable `that`.
@Crazy Train : I know it's not typical, but I found both this problem and the way of implementing this interesting. I wanted to have other's answers and points of view.

Answer (score 3):

Simply save the scope you want to use to a variable.  Tested in JSFiddle.

```
var Bidule = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.value = 8 ;

    this.calc = {
        plus : function(x) { return self.value + x ; },
        minus : function(x) { return self.value - x ; },
        square : function() { return self.value * self.value ; }
    }

    this.fn = {
        random : {
            set : function() { return self.value = random() ; },
            add : function() { return self.value += random() ; }
        }
    }
} ;
```

Comment: Yeah sure, it would work. However your constructor doesn't use a prototype : `var Bidule = function() { var self = this ; ... } ; Bidule.prototype = {} ;`. Here the prototype won't access `var self`.
We could put the prototype like this : `var Bidule = function() { var self = this ; this.prototype = { ... } ; }` but it means the prototype will be set each time the constructor is called, so this is not a good way either.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to make fn a function that returns an object. See my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/txANC/

Comment: Yeah indeed, that is quite a good way. However we'll have to improve it as in your example, `fn()` will build those methods each time it is called. But maybe there is a way to export the clustered methods in 'fn' outside and returning only a reference.